# convert 1-d String array to 2-d char array?

Tags: java, arrays, char, converters, type-2-dimension

I am given:

```
    static String[] initStrings =
{
    "...../...\\",
    "..\\.......",
    "......./..",
    "..........",
    "........\\.",
    "..........",
    "..........",
    ".....\\../.",
    "..\\....../",
    ".........."
};
```

and something like this:

```
    static char[][] squares = 
{

};
```

Now, I need to write a method that will copy each character from each initStrings string into squares array. 
So far I have this:

```
    public static void initialize()
{
    int lengR = initStrings.length;
    int lengC = initStrings[0].length();
    squares = new char[lengR][lengC];
    for(int i=0; i<lengR;i++)
    {
        squares[i] = initStrings[i].toCharArray();
    }
}
```

I am very new to this and I'm pretty sure my for loop is wrong.. I don't see any errors so far, but I just don't understand how my initialize method would work. How do you convert 1-dimensional String array to 2-dimensional Char array? 
Please help me out.. :(

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your `for` loop: a 2D array in Java is a 1D array of 1D arrays; String's `toCharArray` returns one of these 1D arrays. Your `for` loop puts them together into an array of arrays, so the result is a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with 2 for loops addressing each entry in squares:

```
for (int i=0; i<lengR; i++) {
    for (int k=0; k<lengL; k++) {
        squares[i][k]=initStrings[i].charAt[k];
    }
}
```